# CiviCRM - Sage Pay integration Issue

Tags: joomla

Sage Pay was throwing 5006 error upon submission of card details. When we set Location type as "Home" in CiviCRM, we were able to complete transaction without any issues. But when we set Location type as "Work", we'll either get 5006 error or transaction will be cancelled by the system. Do you have any idea why and how "Location type" is affecting in transaction through Sage Pay.

If you could guide us in resolving above mentioned issues, it would be really helpful for us to find the root cause for the challenges encountered.

Thanks in advance for your great support.

We are using following versions:

CiviCRM - 4.6.8
Joomla - 3.4.8
Sage Pay - 3.1.0